# overloading assignment operator - polymorphic containers

Tags: c++, inheritance, operator-overloading, assignment-operator

i have a base class, 2 derived classes and an entitymanager class that has a container of base pointers pointing to derived objects. i have a virtual clone method in the base to take care of the copy constructors in the derived classes, but im having trouble wrapping my head around overloading the assignment operator and preventing slicing, could someone please help with that and perhaps review how ive handled the entitymanager copy constructor? i think its ok

```
class System
{
public:
    virtual System* clone()=0;
};

class projectile :public System
{
public:
    projectile* clone()
    {
        return new projectile(*this);
    }
};

class player : public System
{
public:
     player* clone()
    {
        return new player(*this);
    }
};

class EntityManager
{
private:
    vector<System*> theEntities;
public:
    EntityManager(){}
    EntityManager(EntityManager& other)
    {
        for (size_t i=0;i<other.theEntities.size();i++)
            theEntities.push_back(other.theEntities[i]->clone());
    }
    void init()
    {
        projectile* aProjectile = new projectile;
        player* aPlayer = new player;
        theEntities.push_back(aProjectile);
        theEntities.push_back(aPlayer);
    }
};

int main (int argc, char * const argv[]) 
{
    EntityManager originalManager;
    originalManager.init();
    EntityManager copyManager(originalManager);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is there a specific bug/problem you've encountered?  If this is just a code-review question, would be more suitable at http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: my specific problem is i need to know how to overload the assignment operator given polymorphic containers.

Comment: @coolmrcroc Could you provide a specific example of where you think the slicing could happen?

Comment: nothing ive done so far. i just need to know how to overload the assignment operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a `swap` member that swaps the containers, then implement assignment as copy and swap:

```
void swap(EntityManager& other)
{ theEntities.swap(other.theEntities); }

EntityManager& operator=(EntityManager other)
{ swap(other); return *this; }
```

The argument to the assignment operator will be copied using the copy constructor you've already written, then you swap the data, so the data that belonged to `*this` will be destroyed when that parameter goes out of scope, and `*this` owns the newly copied data.

Re-using the copy constructor in this way means you only need to implement a correct copy constructor (and correct swap, which is usually easy to get right) and your assignment operator is really simple and automatically correct.

N.B. your `init` member and copy ctor are not exception safe, if any `push_back` operation throws an exception you leak memory. You're also missing a destructor, but I assume that's present in the real code.

Comment: +1, whenever you can, you should always implement `swap` (also offer a free function `swap`). That will help in simplifying code and providing exception guarantees.